# how to make ec2 filter using region

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Dears,
I wrote code to list EC2 instances

```
AmazonEC2Client amazonEC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client("id", "password", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))           
DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = amazonEC2Client.DescribeInstances(describeInstancesRequest);
```

I need to add filter to change default region.

I try:

```
var ii = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("region");
```

variable I will return nothing.

and I try:

```
describeInstancesRequest.Filters.Add(new Filter("region-name", new List<string>() { region }));
```

and that's wrong!

Advise please
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query instances of region-1 when using client for region-2. In the above example you have created client with region as Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1

This client will returns instances for USEast1 only. To query instances for other regions you need to create a new client for each region by providing name of that region.

Comment: Thank you,, I solve it by send the Updated Region End Point Every Time and new client instead of using Filter